# maven selenium cucumber junit - timeout received from renderer - why does it sometimes have a positive value and sometimes negative

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

We have test cases running and recently have been running into "timeout received from renderer" errors. What I'm trying to understand is what the values displayed actually mean. Running a test suite we get the following log messages within the same run:

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 180.000
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
Timed out receiving message from renderer: -1023.181
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 179.520
```

The `180` value I get as we have
`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
But I have no idea where the other values are coming from.

Question 1:
What's the difference between a positive value and a negative value?

Question 2:
Any idea where the other values (not the 180) might be coming from especially the `600`?

Question 3: is a negative value a longer timeout than a positive value?

```
java version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
chromedriver version: 111.0.5563.64
selenium version: 3.9.1
cucumber/junit version: 4.8.1
```